# Ajax call hiding API key from client side?

Tags: ajax

Firstly,  I couldn't find an answer for my problem.

The problem is when I am making a call , I have to add the api key in the header. I am using Ajax but I dont want others seeing the api key from the devtool.

My code looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#login").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'/resource/auth/login',
        data: {
              username: username.value,
              password:password.value
            },

        headers: { "ApiKey": "mykey" },
        success: function(){
          alert("Logged in");
```

Is there  a way to hide the value of "mykey", the api call wont work if I dont provide the key in the header

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can make them encrypt and then send to the server, where it can be decrypt

Comment: @WaseelAhmadMufti Oke and how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I will work for you, this code for view:

```
@php
$secret_key = hash('sha256', 'some_secret_key');
$secret_iv = substr(hash('sha256', 'some_secret_iv'),0,16);
@endphp

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#login").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'/resource/auth/login',
    data: {
          _token:{{csrf_token()}}
          username: "{{openssl_encrypt('your_username','AES-256-CBC', $secret_key, 0, $secret_iv)}}",
          password: "{{openssl_encrypt('your_password','AES-256-CBC', $secret_key, 0, $secret_iv)}}"
        },

    headers: { "ApiKey": "{{openssl_encrypt('your_apikey','AES-256-CBC', $secret_key, 0, $secret_iv)}}" },
    success: function(resp){
      console.log(resp);
      },
    error: function(err){ 
      console.log(err);
     }
}
);
```

in Controller's Function you can decrypt is to get username and password:

```
public function login(Request $request){
  $secret_key = hash('sha256', 'some_secret_key');
  $secret_iv = substr(hash('sha256', 'some_secret_iv'),0,16); 

  $username = openssl_decrypt($request->input('username'), 'AES-256-CBC', $secret_key, 0, $secret_iv);
  $password = openssl_decrypt($request->input('password'), 'AES-256-CBC', $secret_key, 0, $secret_iv);
  $apikey = openssl_decrypt($request->header('ApiKey'), 'AES-256-CBC', $secret_key, 0, $secret_iv)

  echo 'Hye! your username is ' $username. ',your password is '. $password .'and your api key is '.$apikey;

  }
```

here openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt are php functions, you can read about them in the documentation:
[openssl_encrypt:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)

[openssl_decrypt:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php)

Make sure that your secret_key and secret_iv should be same on both sides.